# PHP rand generating zeros even though range is supposed to be 2 to 36?

Tags: php, captcha

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numITER; $i++) {
    $val = rand(2,36);

    switch (TRUE) {
        case ($val<=10):
            $vercodeTEMP.=$val;
            break;
        case ($val>10):
            if ($val != 25 && $val != 19) {
                $vercodeTEMP.=chr(54+$val);
            } else {
                $i=$i-1;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm basically trying to avoid 0, 1, and the letters O and I.  How can this possibly be giving me zero's when the rand range is 2 to 36?

Comment: Are you sure that the rand-function is actually giving you zeroes? Can they possible come from somewhere else? Or if you are looking at the finished vercodeTEMP-string, might it be the numbers 10, 20 and 30 that are giving you zeroes in the string?

Comment: Boooooo to the `switch` abuse.  Use an `if` statement, that's what it was designed for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $val == 10, then you will append $val onto $vercodeTEMP.

Try:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numITER; $i++) {
    $val = rand(2,36);

    if ($val<10) {
        $vercodeTEMP.=$val;
    } else if ($val != 25 && $val != 19) {
        $vercodeTEMP.=chr(54+$val);
    } else {
        $i=$i-1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm basically trying to avoid 0, 1, and the letters O and I

What about not messing with magic numbers (besides position) and using PHP's [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)?

```
$numbers = range(2, 9);
$letters = range('a', 'z');
unset($letters[8], $letters[14]);
$letters = array_merge($letters, array_map('strtoupper', $letters));

$pool = array_merge($numbers, $letters);

shuffle($pool);

$captcha = join(array_slice($pool, 0, $numITER)); // e.g. 2ESQcnMTNy
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wjmkb1).

Comment: Pretty cool solution, but seeing as how I just learned php last night, I'm going to stick with something that a little more closely resembles C++ that I'm used to rather than using something that resembles a library-backed solution.